# How do I align the middle cell of multiple tables?

Tags: html, css

```css
div, td, table {border: 1px solid black; }
    div {display: inline-block;}
    .middle {background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
Not aligned:
<div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign=bottom>short text</td>
            <td class="middle">middle</td>
            <td valign=bottom>very ------------------------ long</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign=bottom>very ----------------- long</td>
            <td class="middle">middle</td>
            <td valign=bottom>short text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br>
Aligned manually:
<div>
<table style="margin-left: 6em;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign=bottom>short text</td>
            <td class="middle">middle</td>
            <td valign=bottom>very ------------------------ long</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign=bottom>very ----------------- long</td>
            <td class="middle">middle</td>
            <td valign=bottom>short  -</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Centering the table doesnt work: there is different size of content on both sides.

I can't combine both into the same table: I want to preserve the borders which are the same size as the content.

I hope there is a way to do this without javascript. That would be the last resort.

Comment: Would you be able to put them on the same table and add the borders yourself?

Comment: @Davedude That would make it more complex, because content has things that depends on parent's size (the cell size)

Comment: @Davedude More specifically, there are elements that are centered within each cell.